# Sequence is Convergent or Divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$(1+\frac{5}{n})^{2n}$$
I need to figure the limit if it converges or state if it goes to $$ \pm\infty $$ or simply "divergent" if it diverges but not to infinity.  
  
From what I can tell as n -> infinity
$$\frac{5}{n} -> 0  $$
so would it be the same as evaluating 
$$(1)^{2n}$$
which would just = 1 ?

or do i need to do some form of squeeze theorem like 
$$(\frac{5}{n})^{n} <(\frac{5}{n})^{2n} <(1+\frac{5}{n})^{2n}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\left(1+\frac{5}{n}\right)^{2n}=\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n/5}\right)^{n/5}\right]^{10}$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$$

Answer (score 2):

The sequence
$$\left(1+\frac an\right)^n$$
converges to $e^a$ as $n\to\infty$. So, your sequence tends to $e^{10}$.